# Can I perform a stratified test againts a true value?

Tags: stratification

I have a study where they randomized patients into 2 groups (A and B). The primary aim is to compare group A against a fixed/ true value of 0.75. The binomial test is not stratified and cochran mantel haenszel needs 2 groups. How can I perform a stratified test for risk differences against a true value?